# Cocoa touch how to run a UIAlertView inside a while loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, while-loop, uialertview

I have an int where someone sets how many spellings there are called `samount` and a int called `amountdone` and they are both set to 0 like this `NSInteger samount = 0;
NSInteger amountdone = 0;`at the start. I have a button and when it is clicked it calls the method Startese. The code is

```
  - (IBAction)Startest:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *amount = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Amount" message:@"How much spellings are there" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"That amount" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[amount setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

[[amount textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

[amount setTag: 0];
[amount show];
```

}
And I need a UIAlertView to display its self and then add its text in to an array I have got the `alertView clickedButtonAtIndex` void working like this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (alertView.tag)
    {
        case 0: /* amount alert */
        {

                samount = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];

             UIAlertView *spellings = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Enter Spelling " message:@"Pleaseenter ONE of the spellings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [spellings setTag:1];
            [spellings setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
            [spellings show];



        }
        break;

        case 1: /* Spellings alert*/{

            while (amountdone < samount) {

                  amountdone = amountdone + 1;

            self.myarry = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];

            }

        }
            break;
    }
}
`
```

It works the first time but once the while loop activates it freezes the app does anyone know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create method to create and launch your alertView and in clickedButtonAtIndex: method call after delay;

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethodForLaunchingAlertView:) 
            withObject:objectOrNill 
            afterDelay:0.5];
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Its good, but how would I repeat this a certian amount of times

Comment: It depends whats your requirements, if you want to call it every 0.5s you can do it via for loop, for example: for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethodForLaunchingAlertView:) 
            withObject:objectOrNill 
            afterDelay:i*0.5f];
    }. But I believe you want to run it once user dismissed the previous alertView.

Comment: This code just keep running alert views and it doesn't wait for user dismiss, what cause problems. You should show one alert and when user dismiss it you should show another one and so on. The best way to achieve this is create variable which will keep count of how many times you want the alert view to show and when user dismiss it decrease it and if not zero show another alert.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason it is locking up is because `amountdone` is never set to anything other than the initialization of 0, so `amountdone < samount` is likely always `true`, and therefore your `while` loop continues forever.

When is `amountdone` suppose to be set?

**Edit**

I don't think you want a `while` loop. Based on what you've got

```
while (amountdone < samount) {

    amountdone = amountdone + 1;

    self.myarry = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];

}
```

The `while` loop provides no value, it may as well be an `if` condition because you're setting the same thing over and over again (which setting `NSString` to `NSArray` doesn't make sense either).

I think it's time to take a step back and reevaluate the problem you're solving and your approach. Maybe I can help if you describe the use-case/business requirement.

Comment: Baiscly, I need the UIAlertView to apper a certian number of times and set its text to an array